# Convert a table array to JSON object

Tags: javascript

I am working on a function for converting a table array to JSON and this is my code. I have checked strJSON is the JSON format I want, but it is a string instead of an JSON object. An error message prompts out saying that "Darren is not defined" when I try to convert it into JSON with "eval". I dont know what is happening.

```
var myArray=[["Name","Age","Gender"],["Darren",31,"Male"],["Gakki",25,"Female"]];

//expected output
var myJSON=[{"Name":"Darren","Age":31,"Gender":"Male"},{"Name":"Gakki","Age":25,"Gender":"Female"}];

function convertJSON(tableData){
    var objJSON=[];
    var strJSON=[];
    tableData.forEach(function(rowData,i){
        if (i==0){
            rowData.forEach(function(cellData){
                head.push(cellData);
            });
        }
        else{
            var objData=[];
            var objEntry=[];
            rowData.forEach(function(cellData,j){
                 objData=head[j] + ":" + cellData;
                objEntry.push(objData);
             });
            strJSON.push("{" + objEntry + "}");
        }
    });
    objJSON=eval("[" + strJSON + "]");
    return objJSON
}
```

Comment: You don't convert things into JSON with eval, you use `JSON.parse` and you don't even need to do that at this point since strJSON would be JSON already if you did it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to create a JSON string manually. Put together a normal object and use `JSON.stringify` to convert.

```js
var myArray=[["Name","Age","Gender"],["Darren",31,"Male"],["Gakki",25,"Female"]];

//expected output
var myJSON=[{"Name":"Darren","Age":31,"Gender":"Male"},{"Name":"Gakki","Age":25,"Gender":"Female"}];

function convertJSON(tableData){
    var keys = tableData[0],
        objects = [];
        
    for(var i = 1; i < tableData.length; i++){
        var rowObject = {};
        tableData[i].forEach(function(item, index){
            rowObject[keys[index]] = item;
        });
        objects.push(rowObject);
    }
    
    return JSON.stringify(objects);
}

document.write(convertJSON(myArray));
```

Comment: myArray is being modified after shift();, How to keep it unchange?

Comment: I edited the code so it doesn't need to call `shift()`, and leaves your original array intact.

Answer (score 3):

1. Get 1 element and remove it in original array by [Array#shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift?v=example)
2. Then use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) to build your expect result

```js
var myArray=[["Name","Age","Gender"],["Darren",31,"Male"],["Gakki",25,"Female"]];

var properties = myArray.shift();

var result = myArray.map( a => {
  var newObj = {};
  properties.forEach ( (p, idx) => {
    newObj[p] = a[idx];
  });
  return newObj;
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function html2json() {
   var json = '{';
   var otArr = [];
   var tbl2 = $('#dest_table tr').each(function(i) {        
      x = $(this).children();
      var itArr = [];
      x.each(function() {
         itArr.push('"' + $(this).text() + '"');
      });
      otArr.push('"' + i + '": [' + itArr.join(',') + ']');
   })
   json += otArr.join(",") + '}'

   return json;
}
```